# Python - How to add values to a key with existing values in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

First of all I'm a beginner in Python

I have this dictionary:

```
d={'Name': ('John', 'Mike'),
   'Address': ('LA', 'NY')}
```

Now I want to add more values in the keys like this.

```
d={'Name': ('John', 'Mike', 'NewName'),
   'Address': ('LA', 'NY', 'NewAddr')}
```

I tried update and append but I think it just works in list / tuples, and also I tried putting it in a list using d.items() and then overwriting the d dictionary but I think its messy and unnecessary?

Is there a direct method for python for doing this?

Comment: can you show us the code please

Comment: First of all the value is a tuple you can not append to tuple

Comment: I declared the initial items (john, mike and la, ny)

Comment: a simple question and there is a tsunami of answers :P same like there is a naive customer in a huge marker

Comment: Bam! Lots of similar answers on this one; I saw them in time before posting mine :P.

Answer (score 6):

A tuple `()` is an immutable type which means you can't update its content. You should first convert that into a `list` in order to mutate:

```
>>> d = {'Name': ['John', 'Mike'],
         'Address': ['LA', 'NY']}
>>> d['Name'].append('NewName')
>>> d['Address'].append('NewAddr')
```

Alternatively, you can create a new tuple from existing one along with the string that you want to add:

```
>>> d['Name'] = d['Name'] + ('NewName',)
>>> d['Address'] = d['Address'] + ('NewAddr',)
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply add a `tuple` to `existing value`

```
d={'Name': ('John', 'Mike'),
  'Address': ('LA', 'NY')}

d["Name"]=d["Name"]+("lol",)
print d
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you should use a `list` which is mutable as the value of the dictionary rather than a `tuple` which is immutable.

```
d={'Name': ['John', 'Mike'], 'Address': ['LA', 'NY']}

d['name'].append('NewName')
d['Address'].append('NewAddr')
```

Then, `d` is

```
{'Name': ['John', 'Mike', 'NewName'], 'Address': ['LA', 'NY', 'NewAddr']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
>>> d['Name'] += "NewName",
>>> d
{'Name': ('John', 'Mike', 'NewName'), 'Address': ('LA', 'NY')}
```

Don't forget `,` after `"NewName". Since you want to add it to tuple.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use a `defaultdict` of lists:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)

d['Name'] += 'John'
d['Name'] += 'Mike'
print (d)

defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Name': ['John', 'Mike']})
```

That avoids the special case for initial list creation.

Answer (score 0):

```
d['Name'] = d['Name'] + ('NewName',)  # note the trailing comma!
```

Since tuples are immutable, you need to create a new tuple from the existing one by combining it with the new element into a new tuple. Or use a list instead of a tuple:

```
d = {'Name': ['John', 'Mike']}
d['Name'].append('NewName')
```

The second approach is preferable, because you don't create a new tuple each time you want to add a new name.

FWIW, for tuples you use normal parentheses `()`, and the angular ones `[]` for lists (the difference might not be immediately obvious if you are a beginner).

**Edit:** the last paragraph is by no means meant to be insulting or anything, it was written with good intentions, but could perhaps be reworded a bit. I just wanted to make sure the syntactic differences between creating a `tuple` and a `list` are understood, as the difference is tiny and sometimes creates a confusion among the newcomers to Python. I apologize if it sounded rude.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using tuples you will have to recreate it each time as tuples are immutable:

```
 d[key] = d.get(key, tuple()) + (newelm,)
```

But if you're going to append you better use list:

```
 d = { "key1" : ["val1a", "val2a"],
       "key2" : ["val2"] }

 try:
     d[key].append(newelm)
 except KeyError:
     d[key] = [newelm]
```

If you're sure the key already exists (or if it's an error if it doesn't) in the dict there's no need to use `try`-`except`:

```
 d[key].append(newelm)
```

Comment: It would be nice if when downvoting an answer there were an explaination to why it was downvoted - that way I could improve my answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote but `d.get(key, tuple() + (newelm, )` throws syntax error.

Comment: @ozgur Thank's for the feedback, I've added the missing parenthesis.

Comment: It's easy to fire a downvote and forget about it, but it takes a bit more effort to explain, _why_ an answer is incomplete and/or _how_ it could be improved. It sometimes tells more about the downvoter than the answer itself. Your answer was fine, @skyking, syntax errors happen.