# How can I add values to just one key in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to add more than one value to a key in a dictionary, for example:

```
dictionary={'id':(value1,value2)}
```

How could I add value3 without overwriting id, value1 and value2?

Sorry, this is my first ask

Thank you

Comment: `new_t = list(dictionary['id'])` 
`new_t.append(value3)` 
`dictionary['id'] = tuple(new_t)`

Comment: exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32004096/4661269

Comment: A somwwhat unusual use of a dictionary, are you sure you want exactly this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

`new_t = list(dictionary['id'])`

`new_t.append(value3)`

`dictionary['id'] = tuple(new_t)`

Answer (score 0):

the value you're storing there is called a tuple, and in python tuples are immutable, so you can't add another value. The best you can do is create a new tuple with the two old values and a new one:

```
dictionary={'id':(value1,value2)}

dictionary['id'] = (dictionary['id'][0], dictionary['id'][1], value3)
```